# Linear transforming on cyclic space.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:W \to W$ be a linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space $W$ over a field $F$. We say that $W$ is a cyclic space for $T$ if $W=\operatorname{span} \{v,TV,T^2v,...,T^kv,...\}$ for some fixed element $v$ in $W$.

$a$. Prove that there must be a non-trivial relation of the form $c_0v+c_1Tv+...+c_{d-1}T^{d-1}v+T^dv=0$ with the coefficient of $T^dv$ being $1$.

$b$. Prove that $v, Tv, ..., T^{d-1}v$ is a basis for $W$. Hence $\dim W =d$.

$c$. Find the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to this basis.

$d$. Justify the following statements: $p(T)w=0$ for all $w \in W$ and $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $T$.

I have no idea how to do this problem. Can someone help me please? My thought is to find the relation on $v,Tv, T^2v,...$, however I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Think: it is possible that $v,Tv,T^2v,\cdots$ be linearly independent?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I think when $d > dim W$, $v, Tv, T^2v,...T^dv$ must be dependent. Then this must be a non-trivial solution for the coefficients but since the coefficient of $T^dv$ is $1$, what can I do for it?

Comment: Divide by the coefficient of $T^d v$ (can be 0?)?

Comment: And $d=\dim W$ because you have $d+1$ vectors.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla It was given that the coefficient of $T^dv$ is 1, so  it cannot be $0$.

Comment: The *original* coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**. (a) Let $W_k = \def\s{\operatorname{span}}\s\{T^n v : n \le k\}$, then $$ W_0 \subseteq W_1 \subseteq W_2 \subseteq \ldots $$
Show that there must be a minimal $d$ such that $W_{d-1} = W_d$. What does this tell you about $T^d v$? Show that for $k \ge d$ we have $W_k = W_{d-1}$ (and hence $W = W_{d-1}$).

(b) Use (a) and the fact that $v, \ldots, T^{d-1}v$ is linear independent.

(c) Just use the definition.

(d) This follows again from (a).

Comment: $T^dv$ must be a linear combination of $v,Tv,T^2v,...,T^{d-1}$, so that we $-T^dv$ must also be a linear combination of $v,Tv,T^2v,...,T^{d-1}$. Is that true?    And for (c), since $v,Tv,T^2v,...,T^{d-1}$ is a basis for $W$, the matrix representation will be $\{T(v),T(Tv),...,T(T^{d-1}\}$. Is it right?

Comment: I still don't get (d). We can let $c_ov+c_1Tv+...+c_dT^dv=0$ since $v,Tv,...,T^dv$ must be linearly dependent, there must a non-trivial solution for c's. What does this tell about $p(x)$?